# Combining boxplots in R

Tags: arrays, r, boxplot

I have a plotting question regarding boxplots (using base graphics).

I have several arrays of data which I wish to turn into box plots and compare. The arrays reflect different experiments and what I would like to show is the base results and the percentage difference for the experiments (on one plot!). I.e. the base results on the 1st y axis and the % diff on the second y axis:

```
base <- array(runif(12*24*3), dim=c(12,24,3))
exp1 <- array(runif(12*24*3), dim=c(12,24,3))
exp2 <- array(runif(12*24*3), dim=c(12,24,3))
exp3 <- array(runif(12*24*3), dim=c(12,24,3))
exp4 <- array(runif(12*24*3), dim=c(12,24,3))

# calc p.diff
p.diff   <- function(mod,base)  {
                 100.0*((mod-base)/base) }

a <- p.diff(exp1,base)
b <- p.diff(exp2,base)
c <- p.diff(exp3,base)

# combine the % diff arrays
exps <- list(a,b,c)

# plot the results
boxplot(base, xlim=c(1,4), col="gray", xaxt="n", ylab="Base values", outline=FALSE)
axis(side=1, 1:4, labels=c("base","% exp1","% exp2","% exp3") )
par(new=TRUE)
boxplot(exps, col="red", ylim=c(-200,200), outline=FALSE, axes=FALSE)
axis(4)
grid()
```

This almost works but I don't get the positioning of the different box plots right (if you run my example you will see what I mean). So is there a better way to control the placement of the box plots? Or a better way to produce a similar type of figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited (1): You need to define the rigth sequences for the X axis. So that the plots don't overlap. Just try to play with it.

I think the labels of the X axes are not at the right place? I don't know a more elegant way of doing it but here is a solution:

```
# plot the results
boxplot(base, xlim=c(1,4), col="gray", xaxt="n", ylab="Base values", outline=FALSE)
axis(side=1,1,labels=('base'))
par(new=TRUE)
boxplot(exps, col="red", ylim=c(-200,200), outline=FALSE, axes=FALSE)
axis(4)
axis(side=1,1:3,labels=c("% exp1","% exp2","% exp3"))
grid()
```

So I added every label after creating the `boxplot`. First plot the `base` and label it, then plot `exps` and label it. Does it solve your problem?

Edit: Just to be more clear, You are adding a new plot with 3 values, that is why `axis(side=1,1:3,labels=c("% exp1","% exp2","% exp3"))` is from 1 to 3...

Edited (2):

Why don't you use multi rows in the plot and try to plot 2 graphs? Here is an example with your data:

```
#divide your plottin area into 2 columns with one row.
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
# plot the results
boxplot(base, col="gray", xaxt="n", ylab="Base values", outline=FALSE,axes=FALSE)
axis(2)
axis(side=1,1,labels=('base'))
segments(0,0,1,0)
boxplot(exps,col="red", xaxt="n", ylim=c(-200,200), outline=FALSE, axes=FALSE)
axis(4)
axis(side=1,at=(1:3),labels=c("% exp1","% exp2","% exp3"))
```

you can have more information about it from [here](https://catalyst.uw.edu/workspace/file/download/c24c129d9594e37fcc40cf3d4ae33366b71809ddb9f7499c8d18cb09bf3bdf15)

Comment: Hi Bakya, thanks for this. Its not quite what I was trying to get though. At the moment changing this helps to sort out the positioning of the labels (which is an improvement!) but still if you look at the plot you see that the first red box overlaps the grey box and I would like there t be a gap. I tried adding width=rep(0.8,3) to the second call to boxplot but that doesnt seem to change the width of the box plots..

Comment: Thanks Bakaya, I have opted to just combine them as two plots and have a very small margin between them!